# Looping within a Loop, why does this number output?

Tags: java

```
public class whatever {
    public static void main(String[] arguments){
        int points = 0;
        int target = 100;
        tagetLoop:
        while (target <= 100) {
            for (int i = 0; i < target; i++) {
                if (points > 50)
                    break tagetLoop;
                points = points + i;
                System.out.println("Points: " + points);

            }
        }

    }
}
```

Whenever I run this, the final output would be "Points: 55". Why is it 55 and not 50?

Comment: it should be if(points >= 50)

Comment: do you know what is debugger?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Debugging is a critical skill for all programmers. I strongly suggest that you learn how to use your IDEs built-in debugger. You can also add more System.out.println() statements to your code in order to see what is happening.

Comment: @MonadNewb What confuses me is that the code already *had* that print statement, which should have printed out the `0, 1, 3,` etc series. Given that pattern I'm not sure why the asker would expect it to end with 50.

Answer (score 4):

Because `0 + 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + 6 + 7 + 8 + 9 + 10 = 55`.

Answer (score 3):

The values of `points` will be

```
0, 1, 3, 6, 10, 15, 21, 28, 36, 45, 55
```

It won't exit with the value 50 because it will never be equal to 50.